# Fedora 21 NFSv4 mount hangs for a long time, then times out; showmount -e works

Tags: nfs, fedora-21

I have a fedora 21 server with the following /etc/exports:

```
/mnt/scainet    192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync)
```

On my client on the same subnet, connected to the server through a hub, I run `mount -t nfs scainet:/mnt/scainet /mnt/scainet -v`, which just sits there with this verbose output:

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Thu Jan 22 07:45:55 2015
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.11,clientaddr=192.168.1.12'
```

After a very long while, I get `mount.nfs: Connection timed out`.

`showmount -e scainet` on the client correctly shows the exported directory, albeit after a long time again.

```
Export list for scainet:
/mnt/scainet 192.168.1.0/24
```

I configured NFS largely with the guide of [these instructions](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_21&p=nfs). I did everything except `systemctl enable nfs-lock` and `systemctl enable nfs-idmap`, which didn't work because they are aliases for services (rpc-statd.service and nfs-idmapd.service) that have no [Install] section and are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

I initially suspected this was a firewall problem, so I've enabled nfs, mountd, and rpc-bind through firewall-cmd; it still didn't work, so I manually opened the ports listed by `rpcinfo -p`, and even stopped firewalld altogether. So it doesn't seem to be a firewall problem.

On the server, I can mount the exported directory with the same command (just a different mount point) just fine.

Yet, mount on the client still just sits there with no response, timing out after a several minutes.

How can I get the directories to mount on the client? Did I forget to do something?

EDIT: Here's my firewall configuration from `firewall-cmd --list-all`

```
FedoraServer (default, active)
  interfaces: enp0s25
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http mountd nfs rpc-bind ssh
  ports: 54319/tcp 20048/tcp 2049/udp 111/udp 20048/udp 8000/tcp 53037/udp 51347-51349/udp 2049/tcp 51347-51349/tcp 52375/tcp 111/tcp 44274/udp
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

EDIT 2: `rpcinfo -p scainet` from scainet-2 results in `rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out`.

Comment: All the right ports seem to be open. Check your logs on both the client and server.

Comment: Strange, no new output on either dmesg -w and journalctl -f on both the server and client while `mount -t nfs scainet:/mnt/scainet /mnt/scainet -v` ran. mount still timed out though.

Comment: I'm stumped. I disabled the firewall on both machines. But mount still doesn't work. `rpcinfo -p scainet` results in `rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection timed out
`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was a bug that was fixed in a recent update. Everything works correctly now.